# Retrieving Cloud Firestore `timestamp` value after save

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I'm adding some data to Cloud Firestore:

```js
import { collection, addDoc, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore'; 

const ref = await addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), {
  createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
  modifiedAt: null,
  title: 'A Title',
});
```

I have rules enforcing `createdAt` should equal `request.time` and never be updated, `modifiedAt` should be `null` on create but equal to `request.time` on update, and `title` should be a string.

The problem arises when I try to update this document:

```js
import { doc, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

await updateDoc(ref, {
  createdAt: ???, // what goes here?
  modifiedAt: serverTimestamp(),
  title: 'A Title',
});
```

I need `createdAt` to be that initial server timestamp value (as a `Date` object). I can't just put `serverTimestamp()` because Firestore will try to update that field to the new `request.time` value and rule enforcement will fail. I can't do a partial update (by omitting `createdAt`) because I'm using a client-side ORM (Ember Data), which isn't capable of handling partial updates like this.

**Is there a way to retrieve whatever that initial `serverTimestamp` value became after calling `addDoc`, without making a second request immediately after `addDoc` to retrieve the document we just created?** It seems unnecessary to make that second request, since I already have all the data (sans the timestamp values). I'm basically just trying to avoid adding a second request app-wide every time a new record is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `updateDoc` operation (unlike an `addDoc` operation or the default `setDoc` operation) will only overwrite the keys that you actually specify. So to leave `createdAt` as-is, simply omit it.

```
await updateDoc(ref, {
  modifiedAt: serverTimestamp(),
  title: 'A Title',
});
```

To pluck the key from your CRM, use `delete` on the key.

```
const dataToUpdate = {
  createdAt: "somevalue",
  modifiedAt: serverTimestamp(),
  title: 'A Title'
}
delete dateToUpdate.createdAt;

await updateDoc(ref, dataToUpdate);
```

Additionally, adding a `getDoc` immediately after isn't as network expensive as you think it is. If your application uses that document anywhere in your application (either listening to the document itself or its parent collection), your client app will be notified and given the updated data to store in its local cache regardless of if you need it immediately after adding it.

```
const ref = await addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), {
  createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
  modifiedAt: null,
  title: 'A Title',
});

const snapshotWithServerTimestamps = await getDoc(ref);
```